# RingCentral Embeddable Voice inWeb Application

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, ringcentral, ringcentral-embeddable

I am working in MVC C# Web Application. I am implementing RingCentral Embeddable Voice in my application. I want to paste the number when clicking on call to the Dial pad field which is inside the iFrame of RingCentral. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post a message to Embeddable Voice inside iframe:

```
function postMessage(data) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage(data, '*');
}


postMessage({
    type: 'rc-adapter-new-call',
    phoneNumber: number,
    toCall: false,
});
```

Ref: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-js-widgets/issues/350#issuecomment-325078638